# How does my professor come up with the recursive case in this algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

My professor gave us the following explanation for the recursive algorithm for finding the permutations of a set of numbers:

---

[image]

---

When he has (T(m+1), n-1)) where does that come from? Why is it m+1 and n-1? I'm really confused as to where that comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The $m+1$ arises in two different ways as described that happen to have the same value:  `to pass arguments to each call, it concatenates P to i (the cost is m+1), ...` and $P$ is the set of elements that have been printed, which will have size $m+1$ on iteration $m+2$ in the call to $T(m+1,n-1).$

Because $P$ is a "recursive array of the numbers already printed out," the code must add to $P$ the current item being printed as or after it has been printed.  The cost of this addition is claimed to be $m+1,$ which is presumably a proven result or else a defined condition.  The size of $P$ after this addition also happens to be $m+1$.  This applies to both the "degenerate" case where $S$ has one element and to the recursive case, which is why the term $m+1$ occurs in both formulas.

The $n-1$ term comes from removing an element from the set $S$ as or after it has been printed, so that $S$ has one less term after each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You're picking up the wrong $m+1$ there.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I'm not sure I understand... It seems to me that $m+1$ applies equally to both formulas...  And equally within each formula.  The $T(m+1, n-1)$ term is the one that must be calculated next, the added $m+1$ is the cost due to $P$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The bit you quote talks about the cost: it's explaining the $+m+1$ later in the expression.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: thank you, I had missed the fact that just because the terms had the same value it doesn't mean they arise from the same calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The context is calling $\textrm{printperm}((P,i), S-\{i\})$ recursively from $\textrm{printperm}(P, S)$. The cost of that recursive call is $T(|(P,i)|, |S-\{i\}|)$.

$|(P,i)| = |P| + 1 = m+1$ by definition of $m$.
$|S-\{i\}| = |S| - 1 = n-1$ by definition of $n$.

Comment: As an aside, the "recursive array" datastructure which has a non-constant append cost is not the best choice for this situation.